# Lenovo laptop network drivers

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, thinkpad

I'm installing a new Windows (XP or 7) operating system on my Lenovo laptop. I visited the Lenovo site for [drivers](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/default.page), found the drivers suitable exactly for my laptop:

```
ThinkPad Edge E430 (machine type: 6271-7KG)
```

and installed most of them without any bigger issues. But I got stuck at folder with *wireless network drivers*, because I don't know much about the topic.
The listed wireless LAN drivers are:

- [Broadcom Wireless LAN (802.11a/b/g/n, b/g/n)](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS028674)
- [Realtek 8188CE Wireless LAN Drive (802.11b/g/n)](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS028690)
- [Intel Wireless LAN (802.11/b/g/n)](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS028694)
- [Broadcom BCM43142 Wireless LAN Driver (802.11b/g/n)](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS033286)

**Do I have to install them all or am I supposed to choose between them ???**

I installed mostly all other suggested drivers till now and all of these were suggested exactly for my laptop so I'd install them all too, but they look almost the same... And the third one has about 521MB in size so it seems strange for me.

And I have the same problem with wireless WAN drivers (Do I need them? Do I need them both?):

- [Ericsson H5321 Wireless WAN](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS028661)
- [Sierra Wireless MC8355 - Gobi 3000 Software](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS028624)

From wireless connections I want to use a "standard public WiFi in a restaurant" and occasionally my Huawei E1750. But I feel ashamed I don't know what technology I'm actually using... :-(

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download the [Thinkvantage System Update](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/research/hints-or-tips/detail.page?&DocID=HT073272) for your Operating System, install and run it.  It will find all the latest drivers and install them.  Quick and easy.  No guessing

Comment: Wow, it looks like a wonderful solution! I wondered why installing drivers still had to be so difficult in 2013...  I'm definitely going to try that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Some Lenovo laptops have a slot for a sim card, and an internal GSM modem.  You don't use that if you're using your Huawei dongle.  So you don't need the wireless WAN drivers.

You can find out about the internal WIFI by using "Device Manager".  In vista this is available via Start > Control Panel > Administrative Tools, and then Device Manager under System Tools UNder Computer Management.

There'll probably be a warning icon by Network Adaptors.  Expand that, and right click whatever is there, and select properties.  That should give you plenty of information.